# Swift allowing expansion of all cells except one?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a tableView that's populated with data, where all my cells can currently expand / collapse when tapping on the row.

However, the last cell in my UITableView is a different kind of data, and it should not be expandable when tapped on.

I have it set up so only one cell can be expanded at a time, so if another cell is currently expanded and they tap on the last cell in the UITableView that cell should still collapse, but the last one shouldn't expand.

The way I'm checking if it's the last cell that shouldn't be expandable is checking one of it's labels: `if cell.tickerLabel.text == "  CASH"`

Which I can verify is correct and that if statement runs for the last cell.

I've tried a lot of different implementations of inserting that if statement into my code where I expand and collapse my cells. But none of what I tried has worked as intended.

Here's how my code for expanding / collapsing cells looks like:

My didSelectRowAtIndexPath function
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("com.Stocks.portfolioCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! portfolioCell

```
    if let selectedCellIndexPath = selectedCellIndexPath {
        if selectedCellIndexPath == indexPath {
            self.selectedCellIndexPath = nil
            currentCollapsing = true
            tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
        } else {
            lastCollapsing = true
            self.selectedCellIndexPath = indexPath
            tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([lastIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
            tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
            self.lastIndexPath = indexPath
        }
    } else {
        selectedCellIndexPath = indexPath
        self.lastIndexPath = indexPath
        tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
    }
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

My heightForRowAtIndexPath function

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let SelectedCellHeight: CGFloat = 210
    let UnselectedCellHeight: CGFloat = 50
    if let selectedCellIndexPath = selectedCellIndexPath {
        if selectedCellIndexPath == indexPath {
            return SelectedCellHeight
        }
    }
    return UnselectedCellHeight
}
```

And lastly the part of my cellForRowAtIndePath function that is relevant to this question:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("com.Stocks.portfolioCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! portfolioCell

    cell.heightSeperator.hidden = true
    cell.stockNameView.hidden = true
    cell.purchasePriceView.hidden = true
    cell.lastPriceView.hidden = true
    cell.daysHeldView.hidden = true
    cell.endSeperator.hidden = true

    if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.formulaWhiteColor()
    } else {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }


    if selectedCellIndexPath == indexPath {
        cell.tickerLabel.textColor = UIColor.formulaBlueColor()
        cell.heightSeperator.hidden = false
        cell.stockNameView.hidden = false
        cell.purchasePriceView.hidden = false
        cell.lastPriceView.hidden = false
        cell.daysHeldView.hidden = false
        cell.endSeperator.hidden = false
        tableHeight.constant = tableHeight.constant+210
        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:self.view.bounds.width, height: self.contentView.frame.height)
        self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    if lastCollapsing == true || currentCollapsing == true {
        lastCollapsing = false
        currentCollapsing = false
        tableHeight.constant = tableHeight.constant-210
        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:self.view.bounds.width, height: self.contentView.frame.height)
        self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
```

Can anyone help pointing me in the right direction for how I can make it so my last cell isn't expandable while still allowing any other open cell to collapse when tapping on it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: One thing you're doing wrong is dequeueing a cell in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`; you should never do that inside that method. If you want to get the cell that was selected, you should use the tableView method, `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: oh yeah. I'm not actually using the cell in didSelectRowAtIndexPath, I just forgot to remove it before posting from a previous test where I tried catching the cell from there. It isn't in my code anymore and wasn't my problem. Thanks for pointing it out though :)

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the indexPath is the last one inside `heightForRow`.

Since you can select your last row, the logic will identify that the last row is selected and when calculating it's height, it will calculate as if it were selected (which it was). so you should avoid the last row from being expanded by handling it inside your `heightForRow` delegate method.

*Update*

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let SelectedCellHeight: CGFloat = 210
    let UnselectedCellHeight: CGFloat = 50

    //Add this here, where numberOfRows is self explanatory
    //So replace it with the actually variable.
    if indexPath.row == numberOfRows - 1 {
        return UnselectedCellHeight;
    }

    if let selectedCellIndexPath = selectedCellIndexPath {
        if selectedCellIndexPath == indexPath {
            return SelectedCellHeight
        }
    }
    return UnselectedCellHeight
}
```

Comment: I didn't know indexPath had something to check if it's the last row? This is a perfect solution, but how do I check for this?

Comment: it doesn't have a "last row" property, you would use the `row` property and compare it with the number of rows you have. just compare with the `count` of the array you provide in `numberOfRows` delegate method, *or*  if you use a static value, just use that, but in both cases you would compare like `if (indexPat.row == rows - 1).

Comment: Ahh alright. Give me a moment to try to implement this :) Thanks for the help!

Comment: I can't get it to work, I tried changing my if statement to this: `if selectedCellIndexPath == indexPath && indexPath.row != numberOfRows-1` I'm printing out "numberOfRows" to 17, and indexpath.row to 16. So when tapping the last cell they should both be 16... After that failure I tried making an if statement just below my height variables: `if indexPath.row == numberOfRows-1`. Where i return the unselectedCellHeight. However this didn't work either. Still allows me to expand the last cell. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It still allows me to expand the last cell. :(

Comment: Can you print the `indexPath.row` and `numberOfRows` value right before the `if` you just added?

Comment: `indexPath.row: 16
numberOfRows: 17` However when this prints out, it prints out all of the indexPath rows, a total of 17 times. from 0 - 16. (not sure if that has anything to do with it or not)

Comment: Then, if you compare `indexPath.row == numberOfRows - 1` for the last row, it *Should* work, and the proof is right there.

Comment: if you look at my comments further up, that is exactly what I'm doing. Thanks for the reply though :)